# Clustering a Graph made up of Hamming Distance (Stanford Algorithms - 2)

Tags: algorithm, graph

The problem statement is :

```
In this question your task is again to run the clustering algorithm from lecture, 
but on a MUCH bigger graph. 
So big, in fact, that the distances (i.e., edge costs) are only defined implicitly,
rather than being provided as an explicit list.
The data set is here. The format is:
[# of nodes] [# of bits for each node's label]
[first bit of node 1] ... [last bit of node 1]
[first bit of node 2] ... [last bit of node 2]

For example, the third line of the file 
"0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1" 
denotes the 24 bits associated with node #2.

The distance between two nodes u and v in this problem is defined as the Hamming 
distance--- the number of differing bits --- between the two nodes' labels. For 
example, the Hamming distance between the 24-bit label of node #2 above and the 
label "0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1" is 3 (since they 
differ in the 3rd, 7th, and 21st bits).

The question is: what is the largest value of k such that there is a k-clustering 
with spacing at least 3? That is, how many clusters are needed to ensure that no 
pair of nodes with all but 2 bits in common get split into different clusters?

NOTE: The graph implicitly defined by the data file is so big that you probably 
can't write it out explicitly, let alone sort the edges by cost. So you will have 
to be a little creative to complete this part of the question. 
For example, is there some way you can identify the smallest distances without 
explicitly looking at every pair of nodes?
```

The dataset can be downloaded [here](http://sparkpublic.s3.amazonaws.com/algo2/datasets/clustering_big.txt)

The challenge here is creating the graph faster than O(n^2). The graph has
200,000 nodes so I can't go ahead and calculate Hamming Distances of each and every edge, since 24 bits are used to represent the label, that would add 2^24 = 16mil edges to my graph which is unfeasible.

My take was, convert the binary data to integers and sort them (O(nlgn) time) then, for every vertice represented by the int number create an edge between the current and the next number because the farther the numbers, more the hamming distance will be.

Simplified Eg:

```
000 Let this be node A
001 
010
011  
100 Node B
101
110
111 Node C
```

Now, hamming distance in A and B = 1 , in B and C = 2 and in A and C = 3. I know there are more subtleties here but hammingDistance(A,C) >= hammingDistance(A,B) or hammingDistance(B,C) will always hold.

This way I can make the graph in linear time, imagine this like a straight line and nodes represented on them. Later, I could use disjoint tree/Union Find to cluster them and find the minimum number of clusters as asked in the question.

The testcases in the forum says, for the first 1000 nodes in [this file](http://sparkpublic.s3.amazonaws.com/algo2/datasets/clustering_big.txt), the number of clusters is 989, but my program tells me it's 999.
Also, graphInfo() tells me there are 0 identical edges, 1 edge with weight 1, 0 edges with weight 2. While the actual results are

```
Edges with cost zero: 0
Edges with cost one: 2 
Edges with cost two: 9
```

The code is pretty involved, so please use [this](https://github.com/mayur3086/Stanford-Algorithms-part-2/tree/master/test) link to check the code. I'm unable to figure out whether it's my code or the algorithm that's wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you could use prims or kruskals on the huge tree and then use union find on them?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your algorithm, but I note that it is relatively easy to run https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm in O(n^2) time but only O(n) space. If you look at the more detailed version of the pseudo-code you can see that you only need to keep, for each node, the cheapest cost of any edge linking the small tree currently being grown to that node, and the identity of the edge for that (or, equivalently, the node currently in the tree being grown that you would connect to)

At each stage you find the cheapest link from the tree being grown to a node not in it and then check the links from that new node to see if they provide a cheaper way from the tree being grown to a node not yet in it.

Is it possible that you can afford O(n^2) time but not O(n^2) space? If there are ties, the tree you get from Prim's may not be identical to the tree you would get from Kruskal's, but it will be a minimum spanning tre.

Comment: The problem here is constricting the graph, O(n^2) is too costly. Even if I can find MST in O(nlogn) the entire time will be dominated by constricting the edges, there are too many of them. The trick lies in identifying the edges of cost 1 and 2 in the graph efficiently